# Can general th table styling and class specified th table styling work together?

Tags: html, css, hover

So I have a nicely styled table (atleast thats what I think;)) but I also want the TH's of the table have a pop-up info display.

To make it a bit clearer:

**The nicely styled table**
[image]

**The pop-up on hover of the TH**
[image]

As you can see on the second picture, the styling of the pop-up is overriding the 'general' TH styling.

Now I looked a bit into css overriding but I cant quite figure out how I can make them co-exist.

Anyone has a clue how to fix it?

**The CSS of the general styling (TH only)**

```
td, th {  border: 0 none; height: 30px; }

th {

    background: linear-gradient(#333 0%,#444 100%);
    color: #FFF; font-weight: bold;
    height: 40px;
}
```

**The styling of the hover effect (pop-up)**

```
.hoverEffect{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
.hoverEffect:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 380px;
}

.hoverEffect:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<table>
            <tr>                
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De datum waarop de ticket is aangemaakt.">Datum</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De persoon die de ticket heeft verstuurd.">Verstuurder</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De afdeling of persoon waarvoor de ticket bestemd is.">Ontvanger</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="Het type ticket. De eerste 3 letters geven aan of het voor software of automatisering is (VHS/VHA) en de laatste 3 letters geven aan of het om een probleem gaat (Incident - INC), of om een wijziging (Request for change - RFC)">Soort</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De status van de ticket. 3 mogelijhkheden namelijk 'Nieuw' (New), 'In afwachting' (Pending) en 'Gesloten' (Closed)">Status</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="Het onderwerp van de ticket.">Onderwerp</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De beschrijving van de ticket.">Beschrijving</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="Het verrichte werk aan het probleem/ticket.">Workflow</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De eindoplossing van het probleem/ticket.">Eindoplossing</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td><%=rst("Datum")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Contact")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Ontvanger")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Categorie")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Status")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Onderwerp")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Omschrijving")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Oplossing")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("EindOplossing")%></td>
            </tr>

            </table>
```

Comment: What do you use for `hoverEfffect`? Does it have any tag where you can apply directly your styling (some div or span or whatever tag used)? I mean something as `div.hovereffect` or so. Put it to jsfiddle, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `.hoverEffect` changing the cells display mode from `table-cell` to `inline`. Remove that line from CSS and the table should display correctly.

```css
td, th {  border: 0 none; height: 30px; }

th {

    background: linear-gradient(#333 0%,#444 100%);
    color: #FFF; font-weight: bold;
    height: 40px;
}
.hoverEffect{
    position: relative;
}
.hoverEffect:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 380px;
}

.hoverEffect:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<table>
            <tr>                
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De datum waarop de ticket is aangemaakt.">Datum</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De persoon die de ticket heeft verstuurd.">Verstuurder</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De afdeling of persoon waarvoor de ticket bestemd is.">Ontvanger</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="Het type ticket. De eerste 3 letters geven aan of het voor software of automatisering is (VHS/VHA) en de laatste 3 letters geven aan of het om een probleem gaat (Incident - INC), of om een wijziging (Request for change - RFC)">Soort</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De status van de ticket. 3 mogelijhkheden namelijk 'Nieuw' (New), 'In afwachting' (Pending) en 'Gesloten' (Closed)">Status</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="Het onderwerp van de ticket.">Onderwerp</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De beschrijving van de ticket.">Beschrijving</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="Het verrichte werk aan het probleem/ticket.">Workflow</th>
                <th class="hoverEffect" title="De eindoplossing van het probleem/ticket.">Eindoplossing</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td><%=rst("Datum")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Contact")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Ontvanger")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Categorie")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Status")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Onderwerp")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Omschrijving")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("Oplossing")%></td>
                <td><%=rst("EindOplossing")%></td>
            </tr>

            </table>
```